# GraphQL query exported from ruby gem cannot be compiled using Apollo on Xcode project

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, swift, graphql, apollo

We exported GraphQL queries from ruby gem(graphql 1.9.4) from our server developed using ruby on rails.

Exported file contains dozens of queries.

We also have an iOS Xcode project with Apollo installed.  We tried to make API.swift file using Apollo by running Apollo's script by the query exported from server but it cannot be compiled.

It showed an error like this.

```
Cannot query field "category" on type "Query".
```

We use schema.json which they(server side team) say is the latest.

The queries exported works fine when making query just using curl command.

Used this command to export queries from rails project.

```
bundle exec rails graphql:schema:dump
```

A query tried to build by Apollo iOS(and is exported from the command above.)

```
type Category {
      communities: [Community!]
      id: ID!
      name: String!
}
```

Apollo raises error as below.

```
Cannot query field "category" on type "Query".
```

What is making it wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I turned out that file exported from rails were not in format of GraphQL.
They were plain text describing what queries and mutations were implemented on server with human human readable style.